# Update Firebase Simplelogin email

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

How do I update a users login email address using simplelogin in Firebase?

```
    userRef.update({email:'updatedemail@something.com'})
```

Does not work.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500365/how-do-you-change-the-email-associated-with-a-user-in-firebase-simple-login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500365/how-do-you-change-the-email-associated-with-a-user-in-firebase-simple-login).

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Simple Login](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login) has been deprecated and replaced with a reimplementation of Firebase authentication that is enabled in the core Firebase client libraries. Check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html for the guides on how to get started with it on the web.

With the release of the Firebase Web / Node.js Client v2.1.0, the `changeEmail()` method is built-in, and no longer requires some of the hacks to migrate user ids. Documentation is available at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/changeemail.html.